# CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin() and EOF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am using `CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource` in a spring integration flow:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin())
```

It works. The problem is that if I pipe a file to the process:

```
cat file | java -jar app.jar
```

or

```
java -jar app.jar < file
```

once the file has been read, the EOF is not propagated, the stdin is still active, and the process does not end. Is there something that I can do to make it behave so? Manually entering `ctrl-Z` on the command line works as expected, closing the application (Spring boot app, no web).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it won't work in that scenario; it's designed for console input.

The `CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource` wraps `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` and uses `readLine()`. Since `readLine()` blocks and we don't want to tie up a thread for long periods, we check `reader.ready()`, which returns false if there is no data or the stream is closed.

It should probably provide an option for blocking for this use case, but when used with a real console, it would block forever.

In the meantime, you could create a copy of the class and change `receive()` ...

```
@Override
public Message<String> receive() {
    try {
        synchronized (this.monitor) {
//          if (!this.reader.ready()) {            // remove this
//              return null;
//          }
            String line = this.reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {                    // add this
                ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) getApplicationContext()).close();
            }
            return (line != null) ? new GenericMessage<String>(line) : null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MessagingException("IO failure occurred in adapter", e);
    }
}
```

(removing the ready check, and shutting down the context at EOF).

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4118).

Comment: Just wanted to add that this solution works, but people should be aware that in more complex flows, there might be messages still getting processed and going through the flow which will get lost when the context is closed and all the beans are destroyed. Not sure how to do this gracefully to avoid this kind of situations. Because of that, I ended up not using the `CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource` (with a fix), but have created my own `StdinReader` class which gets invoked from a class implementing a `CommandLineRunner`, and has `ThreadPoolExecutor` autowired to allow executor shutdown.